# text block how to do 1. text trimming 2. vertical alignment for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

text block how to do:

1. text trimming for a given height
2. vertical alignment

Can we use mytextBlock.TextTriming to trim the text?
I have tried to trim text with specifying height but its not working 
same with the vertical alignment.
I tried `TextAlignment = center` 
but its aligning text horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text trimming is not supported in the current version of the framework. However, Robby Ingebretsen's [TextTrimming TextBlock for Silverlight](http://nerdplusart.com/texttrimming-textblock-for-silverlight) works if you recompile it for WP7.

Answer (score 0):

To align the TextBlock vertically you can do this:

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" ... />
```

and ensure that you have the same (or no) margin top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 2 attributes for text trimming for a particular height
TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="Ellipsis"

Along with this you need width or maxwidth value for text wrap to work